# Compile CUDA C++ using CMAKE- More than one compilation phase specified

Tags: c++, cuda, makefile, cmake

I am trying to compile a cuda application (on OSX Yosemite) using CMake. I have the compilation working with a Makefile:

```
CXX = nvcc
CXX_FLAGS = -c -O3 -arch=sm_21
CXX_LIBS = 
BIN = md5_gpu.o

main:
    $(CXX) $(CXX_FLAGS) md5_gpu.cu -o $(BIN) $(CXX_LIBS)
```

This makefile works, and I've tried to port it to CMake. Here is my attempt at making a CMakeLists.txt for the project:

```
### CMakeLists.txt for CUDA

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
find_package(CUDA QUIET REQUIRED)

# Pass options to NVCC
set(CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS};-c -O3 -arch=sm_21)

cuda_compile(md5 md5_gpu.cu)

cuda_add_executable(md5Build ${md5})
```

However, when I attempt to compile this with Cmake (Cmake -> make) an error is thrown that reads:

```
nvcc fatal   : More than one compilation phase specified
CMake Error at cuda_compile_generated_md5_gpu.cu.o.cmake:206
```

Comment: print the content of `CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS`. Namely, after you set the variable, add `message(STATUS "CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS ${CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS}")`. The semicolon in the set command is suspicious, where did you copy your example from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The additional `-c` flag is superfluous, this should work:

```
find_package(CUDA)
list(APPEND CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS "-arch=sm_21;-O3")
cuda_add_executable(md5Build md5_gpu.cu)
```